# Ошибка в написании кода на python

Tags: python, telegram

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Привет, {0}! Я твой личный исторический помощник! Готов узнать что-то новенькое из мира прошлого?".format(update.message.from_user.first_name))

def help(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text('<b>Доступные команды</b>', parse_mode='HTML')

def main():
    token = ""

    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Выдаёт ошибку**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\HistoryWeb\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\HistoryWeb\main.py", line 13, in main
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'
```

**Не понимаю что не так**

Comment: Проверь версию модуля телеграм, и обнови если старый. Либо удали , use_context=True